# Gitlab CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE uses old project's name

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I renamed my project from `old_name` to `new_name`. Then I also changed the path to match `new_name` under Settings -> General -> Advanced and Change Path

When I go to container registry, the "Push an Image" command gives me a path with the new name:

`docker push registry.gitlab.com/path/to/project/new_name`

But when I use the variable `CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE` in the pipeline, it is still giving me `registry.gitlab.com/path/to/project/old_name`.

By changing the path, shouldn't the registry path also change? Because now I'm getting an `UNAUTHORIZED` in the pipeline when trying to publish the image.

This is the command in the pipeline:

`/kaniko/executor --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}" --build-arg "NODE_VERSION=18.15.0" --build-arg "NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN}" --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/$(basename ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}):$CI_COMMIT_SHA" --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/$(basename ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}):latest"`

And this is the error:

`error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: checking push permission for "registry.gitlab.com/path/to/project/old_name/main:some_git_hash": POST https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/path/to/project/old_name/main/blobs/uploads/: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:path/to/project/old_name/main ProjectPath: Type:repository] map[Action:push Class: Name:path/to/project/old_name/main ProjectPath: Type:repository]]`

I've also tried cleaning the runner caches, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that someone added to the project's variables (under Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables) a variable with the same name `CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE` and set it to `old_name`, meaning that even by updating the path, the registry would still be using `old_name`. Next time: check the project's variables!